# is there a code in vba excel which to select window of excel to appear?

Tags: excel, vba

im trying to copy all text from certain pdf file and paste it on myworkbook but i dont know how to go back from window of pdf acrobat to excel window and paste it using that code

sendkeys of alt tab isnt working

```
Sub last()


ActiveWorkbook.FollowHyperlink "C:\Users\Ewallet2\Desktop\New folder\test (1).pdf"
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.Wait (Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 2)) 

   SendKeys "^a"   'Select All
   SendKeys "^c"   'Copy

     Application.Wait (Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 1)) '
     Application.SendKeys ("%{TAB}")
      Application.Wait (Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 1)) 
      SendKeys "%{F4}"    'Close shell application

     ThisWorkbook.Sheets("248").Range("l21").Select
      Application.Wait (Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 1)) 
   Application.SendKeys "^v"

   Next x
End Sub
```

what i want is a line of code to toggle between pdf acrobat and ms excel workbook

Comment: Looks like a Job for `AppActivate()`

Comment: i think i've already tried it. can you please explain to me how to use it on my existing code?

Answer (score 0):

The way to solve this is to work with a specific Excel Range when pasting, rather than mimicking using the keyboard. In other words, `SendKeys` is only necessary for the commands you're sending to the default PDF software installed on the machine. For everything to do with Excel, use Excel's object model.

The following code sample, based on that in the question, declares (`Dim`s) and instantiates (`Set`s) object variables for the workbook, the worksheet and the cell range that is the target for pasting.

```
Sub PasteFromPDF()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range

    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.Sheets("248")
    wb.FollowHyperlink "C:\Users\Ewallet2\Desktop\New folder\test (1).pdf"
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 2))

    SendKeys "^a"   'Select All
    SendKeys "^c"   'Copy

    Application.Wait (Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 1))
    SendKeys "%{F4}"    'Close shell application

   Set rng = ws.Range("L21")
   ws.Paste rng
End Sub
```

Comment: text from pdf only copy but pasting on workbook doesn't work. I used sendkeys "^v" and it work. but it is recommended to use sendkeys function?